# What does the き in わたしわすすけたぶりきのひと mean?

Tags: grammar, words, song-lyrics

I've seen [a translation](https://kazabana.wordpress.com/2019/04/16/niji-no-kanata-ni-over-the-rainbow-reona/) say the line is "I’m a tin person covered in soot", but [ichi.moe doesn't tell me](https://ichi.moe/cl/qr/?q=%E3%82%8F%E3%81%9F%E3%81%97%E3%82%8F%E3%81%99%E3%81%99%E3%81%91%E3%81%9F%E3%81%B6%E3%82%8A%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AE%E3%81%B2%E3%81%A8&r=htr) what the `ki` means in the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's part of ぶりき, which means "tin".

The correct sentence decomposition is:

わたし　わ　すすけた　ぶりき　の　ひと。

Though I assume the わ is supposed to be は.